# How to convert raw String of date to age?

Tags: android

I have a form for putting data inputs and in my birthdate, by the way I am using volley so in my code I am using `jsonResponse`. I did not use things such as `DatePicker` or `CalendarView`. I just set the input type into "date". So I converted it to string and it would be at the format of `MM/dd/yyyy`.

How can I convert my string date into age?

Can someone help me out with a function?

Here is my code.

```
String strBirthDate = "BirthDate: " + object.getString("birth_date").trim();

birthDate.setText(strBirthDate);
```

the string would go out like `1/1/1990`

is there any way to divide these parts and convert it to age?

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/calculate-age-from-date-of-birth/

Comment: What is your expected output? only Year or all?

Comment: I want to try to divide the three and then just show the age, but I can't think of anything to convert it :(

Comment: but its just purely string as I said :( 1/1/1990. is there a way to half them?

Comment: You want to show the output like: `January 1, 1990`?

Comment: No sir @FaysalAhmed, I want to show the age exactly, like if my birthdate being input is 1/1/1990, i should show Age: 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the date string to this method. This will return you the age like `29` if your date is `1/1/1990`.

Try this:

```
public String getAge(String dateString){

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    Date readDate = null;
    try {
        readDate = df.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(readDate.getTime());

    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    dob.set(year, month, day);

    int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
        age--;
    }

    Integer ageInt = new Integer(age);
    String ageS = ageInt.toString();

    return ageS;
}
```

Comment: my birthdate string is named strBirthdate sir, is this right? getAge(strBirthDate);

if then, what should I do next? set the textview to ageS?

Comment: just use this to call `birthDate.setText(getAge(strBirthDate));`. That's it.

Comment: with a little tweaks and rewrites I have got it sir! :) thank you for helping me out!